# unable to update php version to 5.5 on centos

Tags: centos, php

i want to update php version centos via ssh , i ran "yum update" command on server but it did not update php version, how can i do it . Please guide.

My centos version is 6.6

Comment: I'm downvoting the question because it doesn't show effort to solve the problem after `yum update` failed.

Comment: [link to the answer on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502656/upgrading-php-on-centos-6-5-final)

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question; PHP 5.5 isn't provided in Centos 6 repositories

Answer (score 1):

CentOS doesn't provide PHP 5.5 in their standard repositories

Look here; you'll need to use EPEL

https://webtatic.com/packages/php55/

Comment: That isn't EPEL. And I wouldn't touch webtatic packages with a ten foot pole.

Comment: Okay, use REMI or compile from source